# Unable to cut out a shape from an image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, images, mask

I made a house drawing from line segments on Adobe Illustrator CC. I used the join command and wanted to cut out the house shape from a color gradient I downloaded. I tried using “Object > Path > Divide Objects Below” but it's not working. I am sure this is a simple fix but I am a newbie and would greatly appreciate anyones help and input.

Comment: Additional Note: Object>Path>Divide will only work with vector shapes. The gradient you downloaded was probably an image rather than a vector image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make the compound shape of the house you created into a Clipping Mask!

1. Place the image of the gradient in your document
2. Align the house shape that you created over top of the gradient
3. Select both items and from the Menus choose Object > Clipping Mask > Make

[image]

Comment: You are an Angel! Thank you all this is exactly what I needed to do. I do have a follow up question in the matter but since its not directly related to the topic im not sure if I should ask it here or make a new thread. Kindly I ask if I can ask this?

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask. If it's a substantial question, then yea, maybe start a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide an image in Illustrator. Use the gradient tool to fill in your shape. OR if you **really** want to clip an image of a gradient (again, not the correct way, but it's possible) I recommend using a layer mask or clipping mask.

With your image below, draw your shape on top select both and go to:

> Object > Clipping Mask > Make **⌘ + 7** (Ctrl + 7)

Comment: @GoofyMonkey You beat me! I shouldn't have gotten up. :P

Comment: There's a time and place for clipping images/gradients. I quite regularly clip a background image I've created in PS to use in a layout in Illustrator. Drop shadows, layer blend modes, etc... Still safer doing a lot of that in PS if you are going to print!

Comment: I just default to copying vector elements as smart objects to photoshop if working with images. But it's true, there's always a weird case here and there for putting using in Illustrator.